# Android Facebook SDK 4.4.1 - ShareApi.share(...) makes 3 requests

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

Today I updated our Android Facebook SDK to the latest version (4.4.1). I'm now seeing some odd behavior.

When I call:

```
ShareApi.share(contentForSharing(), shareCallback);
```

I see three requests made. The first succeedes:

```
[{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"552185138255521"}, error: null}]
```

The second fails:

```
[{Response:  responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 100, errorType: FacebookApiException, errorMessage: Invalid parameter}}]
```

and the third succeeds:

```
[{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"success":true}, error: null}]
```

Furthermore, the graph story appears on my Activity Log, displaying exactly as expected, but not on my Profile or Home feed pages.

Has anyone else run into this?

Here is my publish code:

```
private void publishToFacebook() {
    ShareApi.share(contentForSharing(), shareCallback);
}
```

... the content builder:

```
private ShareOpenGraphContent contentForSharing() {
    String previewPropertyName = "MyApp:MyObject";
    ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder actionBuilder = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder().setActionType("MyApp:MyAction");
    ShareOpenGraphObject fbObject = buildGraphObject();

    actionBuilder.putObject(previewPropertyName, fbObject);
    actionBuilder.putString("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");

    ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder contentBuilder =
            new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setAction(actionBuilder.build())
            .setPreviewPropertyName(previewPropertyName);

    return contentBuilder.build();
}
```

... the object builder

```
private ShareOpenGraphObject buildGraphObject() {
    if (mLocalObject!=null) {
        Object[] urlArgs = 
                new Object[] {  
                "MyApp:MyObject",
                mLocalObject.getScore(),
                mLocalObject.getTitle(),
                mLocalObject.getDescription(),
                mLocalObject.getSummary() };
        String url = String.format("http://www.myappwebsite.com/obj.php?"+
                                    "fb:app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&og:type=%s"+
                                    "&MyApp:score=%s"+
                                    "&og:title=%s"+
                                    "&og:description=%s"+
                                    "&og:image=http://www.myappwebsite.com/images/icon.png"+
                                    "&body=%s", urlArgs);

        ShareOpenGraphObject obj = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString("og:type", "MyApp:MyObject")
        .putString("og:image", "http://www.myappwebsite.com/images/icon.png")
        .putString("og:image:width", "100")
        .putString("og:image:height", "100")
        .putString("og:title", mLocalObject.getTitle())
        .putString("MyApp:score", mLocalObject.getScore())
        .putString("og:description", mLocalObject.getDescription())
        .putString("og:url", url).build();
        return obj;
    }
    return null;
}
```

... the response callback:

```
private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback =
        new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                dismissProgressDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                if (error instanceof FacebookGraphResponseException) {
                    Timber.d("an error occurred posting to facebook");
                    FacebookGraphResponseException graphError =
                            (FacebookGraphResponseException) error;
                    if (graphError.getGraphResponse() != null) {
                        handleFacebookError(graphError.getGraphResponse());
                        return;
                    }
                }
               dismissProgressDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                if (getActivity() == null) {
                    Timber.d("ACTIVITY IS NULL");
                    // if the user removes the app from the website,
                    // then a request will have caused the session to 
                    // close (since the token is no longer valid),
                    // which means the splash fragment will be shown 
                    // rather than this one, causing activity to be null. 
                    // If the activity is null, then we cannot
                    // show any dialogs, so we return.
                    return;
                }

               dismissProgressDialog();
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               getActivity().finish();
            }
        };
```

... and finally, the error handler

```
 private void handleFacebookError(GraphResponse response) {
     FacebookRequestError error = null;
     if (response!=null) {
         error = response.getError();
     }
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = null;
     String dialogBody = null;

     if (error == null) {
         dialogBody = getString(R.string.error_dialog_default_text);
     } else {
         switch (error.getCategory()) {
         case LOGIN_RECOVERABLE:
             // There is a login issue that can be resolved by the LoginManager.
             LoginManager.getInstance().resolveError(this, response);
             return;
         case TRANSIENT:
             dialogBody = getString(R.string.fb_error_transient);
             break;

         case OTHER:
         default:
            // an unknown issue occurred, this could be a code error, or
            // a server side issue, log the issue, and either ask the
            // user to retry, or file a bug
            dialogBody = getString(R.string.fb_error_unknown, error.getErrorMessage());
            break;
         }
     }

     String title = error.getErrorUserTitle();
     String message = error.getErrorUserMessage();
     if (message == null) {
         message = dialogBody;
     }
     if (title == null) {
         title = getResources().getString(R.string.fb_error_dialog_title);
     }

     new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
     .setPositiveButton(R.string.fb_error_dialog_button_text, listener)
     .setTitle(title)
     .setMessage(message)
     .show();
}
```

Just to note, all of the parameters I'm using are approved and valid (i.e., fb:explicitly_shared, message) and I have checked that my publish method is only called one time throughout the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working; I don't fully understand, but I did.

Notice in the 'contentBuilder' function, I declare the object as "MyApp:MyObject", this is how the graph object is declared in our iOS app. Well, this doesn't work in Android. The object is declared only with "MyObject" ... Again, I don't really understand why this is, but now it's working.